# change default color rotation matplotlib to specific colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to change the standard color rotation of matplotlib to another colormap. To be specific, I would like to use 'gdist_rainbow'. Is that possible and if so, how can i achieve it?

I already have custom settings like

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
params = {'legend.fontsize': 'x-large',
         'axes.labelsize': 'xx-large',
         'axes.titlesize':'xx-large',
         'xtick.labelsize':'xx-large',
         'ytick.labelsize':'xx-large',
         'lines.markersize':8,
         'figure.autolayout':True}
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

So I guess I am just looking for the right key to add.

Comment: I *believe* it is `axes.color_cycle`.

Comment: But `'axes.color_cycle':'gdist_rainbow'` does not work. I tried that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply a color cycle to the `"axes.prop_cycle"` rcParameter. A color cycle consists of a list of colors. Those can be chosen according to a colormap. See example below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler
import numpy as np

# get colormap
cmap=plt.cm.gist_rainbow
# build cycler with 5 equally spaced colors from that colormap
c = cycler('color', cmap(np.linspace(0,1,5)) )
# supply cycler to the rcParam
plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"] = c


x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
f = lambda x, phase:np.sin(x+phase)
for i in range(30):
    plt.plot(x,f(x,i/30.*np.pi) )

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: But I need to set a number for the cycler. That is kind of a downside. Is there an even more general solution?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The whole point of a cycler is that it has a number of elements over which it can cycle.

Comment: But say we plot 2 lines in one axes object. Then it should space the color map according to the number 2. If you predefine it to be spaced into five colors but you end up using only 2 you will end up with suboptimal color distinction. But I guess automatic spacing is not done in default color rotation either? Than it is maybe to much to ask.

Comment: What you are asking for is exactly the concept of a colormap, not a colorcycle. Both concepts are used within matplotlib. However in order to be able to use a colormap the number of elements to colorize needs to be known in advance. It therefore makes sense to use them for results of single plot commands. For multiple successive plot commands, cyclers are used, because they are independend of the number of plots, i.e. how should the second plot know that there will still 4 other plots coming afterwards??? If you, as a user, knows the number of plots, you may still use a colormap, if you like.