# How to set default Matplotlib axis colour cycle

Tags: matplotlib

The default axis colour cycle in Matplotlib 2.0 is called `tab10`:

[image]

I want to use a different qualitative colour cycle, such as `tab20c`:

[image]

I have used this code to change the default axis colour cycle:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler

c = plt.get_cmap('tab20c').colors
plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = cycler(color=c)
```

This looks pretty dirty to me. Is there a better way?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43549777/4124317) shows a slightly different way; it's probably not better though. But unless you clearly define "better", it hard to know what you want really.

Comment: I was hoping for something like `ax.set_color_cycle('tab10')`

Comment: `File "\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 395, in validate_color
   
 if s.find(',') >= 0:

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'find'`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test it, but it should be `ax.set_prop_cycle(cycler(color=plt.get_cmap('tab20c').color‌​s))`

Comment: That works nicely. Could you please add it as an answer?

Comment: `ax.set_prop_cycle(color=plt.get_cmap('tab20c').color‌​s)` also works. According to the documentation, "This is just a shortcut for explicitly creating a cycler".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in the comments, it's not clear what "better" would mean. So I can think of two different ways in addition to the one from the question, which works perfectly fine.

#### (a) use seaborn

Just to show a different way of setting the color cycler: Seaborn has a function `set_palette`, which does essentially set the matplotlib color cycle. You could use it like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_palette("tab20c",plt.cm.tab20c.N )
```

#### (b) set the cycler for the axes only

If you want the cycler for each axes individually, you may use `ax.set_prop_cycle` for an axes `ax`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_prop_cycle(cycler(color=plt.get_cmap('tab20c').color‌‌​​s))
```