# Specifying matplotlib colors for a call to axis.plot() with multiple lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot a 3xN matrix to obtain three lines, specifying the colors for each one. I can do this with three separate calls to [`plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot):

```
fig = plt.figure()
theta = np.arange(0,1,1.0/720) * 2 * np.pi
abc = np.cos(np.vstack([theta, theta+2*np.pi/3, theta+4*np.pi/3])).T
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(theta,abc[:,0],color='red')
ax.plot(theta,abc[:,1],color='green')
ax.plot(theta,abc[:,2],color='blue')
```

[image]

Is there a way to do the same thing, specifying colors with one call to `plot()`?

```
ax.plot(theta,abc,????)
```

I've tried

```
ax.plot(theta,abc,color=['red','green','blue'])
```

but I get `ValueError: could not convert string to float: red` in a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to change the color cycle from which colors are chosen automatically, such that it contains those colors needed for the plot.

```
ax.set_prop_cycle('color', ["red", "green","blue"]) 
ax.plot(theta,abc)
```

This can also be done using rcParams, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549534/change-default-color-rotation-matplotlib-to-specific-colormap).

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
theta = np.arange(0,1,1.0/720) * 2 * np.pi
abc = np.cos(np.vstack([theta, theta+2*np.pi/3, theta+4*np.pi/3])).T
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

ax.set_prop_cycle('color', ["red", "green","blue"]) 
ax.plot(theta,abc)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Where is the index in the color cycle stored? In my real application I'm going to be making several plot() calls to one axis, and I need to control the color to all of the plotted lines.

Comment: It doesn't have any index. But you may reset it by calling the line `ax.set_prop_cycle('color', ["red", "green","blue"]) ` again - after that it will restart at "red". Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, that's not possible. [According to the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-plot) the `color=` argument must be a single color (or an array of 3-4 floats). Is there a particular reason you need to do only one call?

If it must be a one-liner, you could do the following:

```
ax.plot(theta,abc[:,0],color='red',theta,abc[:,1],color='green',theta,abc[:,2],color='blue')
```

which is one line, but does not really save on typing.

Or:

```
for i,c in enumerate(['red','green','blue']):
    ax.plot(theta,abc[:,i],color=c)
```

**EDIT**

Actually, I thought of one way to do this.
If you simply call `plot(theta, abc[:,:])`, the colors [will be cycled through the list of colors in the rcParams `axes.prop_cycle`](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colors-in-default-property-cycle).

Therefore, you could (temporarily) change the color cycle to red,green,blue before calling your plot command.

```
from cycler import cycler

#save the current color cycler
old = matplotlib.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']

#set the color cycler to r,g,b
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = cycler(color=['r','g','b'])

fig = plt.figure()
theta = np.arange(0,1,1.0/720) * 2 * np.pi
abc = np.cos(np.vstack([theta, theta+2*np.pi/3, theta+4*np.pi/3])).T
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(theta,abc)  # <----- single call to `plot` for the 3 lines

#restore original color cycle
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = old
```

Comment: " Is there a particular reason you need to do only one call?" -- for clarity; it's one unified set of data and simpler to read the source code.